# Why my code not working in Python Regex while string extraction

Tags: python, regex

Trying to extract the string and digit from the string, but not doing as expected

```
s = '''
text1
text2
http://url.com/bla1/blah1/text22
text3
'''
import re
re.findall(r'(^http.*|text\d+)',s)
```

My Out, thought was ^http wont consider the line

```
['text1', 'text2', 'text22', 'text3']
```

Expected

```
['text1', 'text2', 'text3']
```

Disclaimer
please don't do `'re.sub(r'http\S+', '', s)'`

Comment: `^` is only in one of your options. Either put it in both or move it outside the capturing group: `(^http.*|^text\d+)` or `^(http.*|text\d+)`.

Comment: Please be clear on what you were trying to do.  `^http` means start-of-line followed by `http`.  You want so find only lines that are NOT started with `http`? what about `text\d+` that are not started from beginning of line? what do you want to find?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect you are trying to find all `text\d+` anywhere within the line, except for lines started with `http` (else I couldn't think of the reason behind that extra `http` check if you just want `text` at start of line)

If so, you can use : `^(?!http).*(text\d+)`.  First capture group is what you need

Python's `re.findAll` returns contents of capture group:

```py
s = '''
text1
text2
http://url.com/bla1/blah1/text22
text3
xyz text4
text555
'''
re.findall(r'^(?!http).*(text\d+)', s, flags=re.MULTILINE)
# ['text1', 'text2', 'text3', 'text4', 'text555']
```

Comment: perfectly working, just one querry, ^http means negating http right?

Comment: No.  `^` here means start-of-line anchor.  `^` means negate only when it appears at beginning of character class: e.g. `[^abc]` means any character other than `a` / `b` / `c`

Answer (score 0):

Try using this one-liner to detect whether it is in the beginning of the string, i add the `re.MULTILINE` flag so it tries to match every line:

```
print(re.findall('^text\d+',s, flags=re.MULTILINE))
```

Output:

```
['text1', 'text2', 'text3']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
re.findall(r'(^text\d+)',s, flags=re.MULTILINE)
```

Use this code at the place of

```
re.findall(r'^(?!http).*(text\d+)', s, flags=re.MULTILINE)
```